# Can I get a user list of those who have asked the most unanswered questions using Data Explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer

In other words: a user list ordered by unanswered question count (ignoring self-answered questions).

Comment: My English is bad. So I don't know that  edit done by yiyi is correct or wrong. Seems like this edit gives another meaning too. It is important that that user should not have receive a answer for any question. I mean I want to get a list of users by question count but they must not be received any answer for any question.

Comment: I apologize if I changed the meaning, I had trouble understanding your question and tried to make it clearer.

Comment: Still, in the same vein as in SO, doing some research and attempting to accomplish your goal on your own before asking   (and sharing your efforts in an eventual question) is always preferable to _"how do I do this?"_ questions, IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
SELECT TOP(10)
    COUNT(*) AS UnansweredCount,
    OwnerUserId  as[User Link]
FROM
    Posts
WHERE
    PostTypeId = 1 AND
    AnswerCount = 0
GROUP BY OwnerUserId, OwnerDisplayName
ORDER BY UnansweredCount DESC
```

[Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/825240/users-who-have-asked-the-most-unanswered-questions).

---

If you want to exclude any Users, who got an answer, here is an alternative query:

```
SELECT TOP(10)
    COUNT(*) AS UnansweredCount,
    OwnerUserId  as[User Link]
FROM
    Posts p
WHERE
    p.PostTypeId = 1 AND
    p.AnswerCount = 0 AND
    p.OwnerUserId NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT OwnerUserId
        FROM Posts p2
        WHERE
            p2.PostTypeId = 1 AND
            p2.OwnerUserId IS NOT NULL AND
            p2.AnswerCount > 0
            
    )
GROUP BY OwnerUserId
ORDER BY UnansweredCount DESC
```

[Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/825243/users-who-have-asked-the-most-unanswered-questions-excluding-any-user-with-any-a)

Comment: Thanks. Seems like you have answered the edited version of the question. I don't know that, that edit is correct ot wrong. Can you please check the comment which I wrote for my question. However, thanks.... But it includes users who has receive some answers.

Comment: See my Update @IamtheMostStupidPerson

Comment: Thanks :-) That is what I need :-)